# Meaning of this quote from Victor Frankl’s book?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was just reading Victor Frankl’s book , *Man’s Search for Meaning*, and came across this quote

> “I mentioned earlier how everything that was not connected with the immediate task of keeping oneself and one's closest friends alive lost its value. Everything was sacrificed to this end. A man's character became involved to the point that he was caught in a mental turmoil which threatened all the values he held and threw them into doubt. Under the influence of a world which no longer recognized the value of human life and human dignity, which had robbed man of his will and had made him an object to be exterminated (having planned, however, to make full use of him first-to the last ounce of his physical resources)-under this influence the personal ego finally suffered a loss of values. **If the man in the concentration camp did not struggle against this in a last effort to save his self-respect, he lost the feeling of being an individual, a being with a mind, with inner freedom and personal value.** He thought of himself then as only a part of an enormous mass of people; his existence descended to the level of animal life. The men were herded-sometimes to one place then to another; sometimes driven together, then apart-like a flock of sheep without a thought or a will of their own. A small but dangerous pack watched them from all sides, well versed in methods of torture and sadism. They drove the herd incessantly, backwards an forwards, with shouts, kicks and blows. And we, the sheep, thought of two things only-how to evade the bad dogs and how to get a little food.”

I would like to know the meaning of the highlighted sentence. I’m confused as to what ‘this’ means , in the part, it “If the man in the concentration camp did not struggle against this in a last effort to save his self-respect”. And how did not struggling against “this” make him feel like he was an animal ?

From what I inferred , *this* refers to the struggle against losing one’s personal values. If a man did not struggle against losing his personal values (i.e. he retained his personal values , as earlier and did not fight for self preservation), he would feel like one among a flock of sheep who have no will of their own and cannot fight for themselves.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I would really like to know the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Yes, _this_ presumably refers to the state of mind described in the previous sentences.

Comment: @KateBunting okay thanks a lot :)